# NGINX epoll_ctl(1, 13) failed (17: File exists)

Tags: nginx

I installed nginx with https://www.virtuozzo.com/ after that I deployed and it worked and I installed SSL then an error occurred epoll_ctl(1, 13) failed (17: File exists) when accessing my website. please tell me what is missing from my nginx settings

my default.conf

```
location / {
root   /var/www/webroot/ROOT/public;
index  index.html index.htm index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    location ~ /\. { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_buffers 32 4k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;          
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
}

location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
root   html; }

location ~ ^/\.well-known { root /var/www/webroot/ROOT;  allow all;}
location ~ /\.well-known { root /var/www/webroot;  allow all;}
location ~ /\. { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location ~ \.php$ {
location ~ /\. { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_buffers 32 4k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/webroot$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/webroot;
```

}

Comment: Why are you tagging [tag:apache] on an nginx question?